# Display Published Posts Count for Certain Time Period

Tags: posts, count

I need some kind of plugin (if it exists) or a wp query which would display number of posts published within a certain time range.

*For example:*

I need to know how many posts have been published since 2015-06-01 until now -- 2015-06-27.

I really hope someone could help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the record using bellow query

```
$posts= get_posts(array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order'   => 'DESC',
            'date_query'    => array(
                'column'  => 'post_date',
                'after'   => '-7 days'  // -7 Means last 7 days 
            )
        ));
echo count($posts);
```

If you want to get last 6 month the use -6 Months

Comment: Thanks.

But unfortunately I'm not a developer, so how should I display the final number?

Because when I type echo $posts;
It just gives me "Array".

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Ok so you need to use the count function let me update code

Comment: I have updated code let me know if you have any prolem

Comment: It works great. That's amazing. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @IGNAS Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

see also [User Published Post Count](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275654/user-published-post-count)

if you've got many posts, you may want to use WP Query

`date_query` has been available since version 3.7

```
$args = [
    'author' => $user_id, 
    'posts_per_page' => 1, //don't need more
    'fields' => 'ids', //don't need more
    'suppress_filters' => true, 
    'date_query' => ['after' => '-6 months']
];

$query = new WP_Query( $args );  
$count_per_author = $query->found_posts; //how many posts match the query args
```

`post_count` is used for how many posts are displayed

for between date A and date B, you can use

```
'date_query' => [
    'after' => '1 January 2019',
    'before' => '31 January 2019'
],

'inclusive' => true,
```

see the WP Codex for more details on [WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), inc. examples of how to use the `date` args and `inclusive` to match exact date values