# User Published Post Count

Tags: author, count

I am need to get this function to get user post count where we get published posts within 24 hours, if none in 24 hours then within the week.

Ex. 
David Green - 10 Posts within 24 hours

Vivian Waters - 5 Posts This Week

Michael Gibbs - 8 Posts This Week

Jordan Gunn - 12 Posts within 24 hours

Here is the function by WordPress that gets ALL posts but I need posts only within 24 hours.

```
function count_user_posts( $userid, $post_type = 'post', $public_only = false ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( $post_type, true, $userid, $public_only );

    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );

    /**
     * Filters the number of posts a user has written.
     *
     * @since 2.7.0
     * @since 4.1.0 Added `$post_type` argument.
     * @since 4.3.1 Added `$public_only` argument.
     *
     * @param int          $count       The user's post count.
     * @param int          $userid      User ID.
     * @param string|array $post_type   Single post type or array of post types to count the number of posts for.
     * @param bool         $public_only Whether to limit counted posts to public posts.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'get_usernumposts', $count, $userid, $post_type, $public_only );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some different approaches:

1. Fetch users with `get_users()` and paginate them with e.g. 10 per page.
   For each user, call `WP_Query` with `date_query` for the last 24 hours, else last week. Use `author` input argument and `posts_per_page` as 1 (we don't need more) and get the total posts from `WP_Query::found_posts`.

   - *pros*: Uses only WordPress API calls
   - *cons*: Multiple `WP_Query` calls, but we limit them by the user per page count.
2. Fetch all posts last 24 hours or last week  with `WP_Query` and `date_query`. Loop through the posts and collect posts count for each post author per week or per 24 hours.

   - *pros*: Uses only WordPress API calls - single `WP_Query` call.
   - *cons*: Doesn't scale well for many posts as we don't want to fetch hundreds of posts!
3. Write custom SQL

   - *pros*: Dedicated single query or queries.
   - *cons*: More fragile as the SQL is written by hand and we're not using WordPress API calls. Gets complicated if we use e.g. joins and that might become slower as the tables grow.

Comment: You mean extending the `count_user_posts()` to support a date query? I think I would just use approach #1 listed here above instead and get the count from `$query->found_posts`;

Comment: OK can you just in the user post count function by WordPress edit the $count variable where we get the time and if not today fetch by the week. Do you have a code example of your method I'm not a backend developer just knowledgeable

Comment: I need this to filter the main query loop in the index.php so if an author is posting too much within 24 hours I can remove their posts in the loop.

Comment: Please edit the question with all relevant info, to avoid guesswork. Not sure what you mean, but you can try e.g. `$args = [ 'author' => $some_user_id, 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'fields' => 'ids',  'suppress_filters' => true, 'date_query' => [['after'  => '24 hour ago',  'inclusive' => true]]];` where you adjust `$some_user_id`. Then `$query = new WP_Query( $args );` and  `$count_per_author = $query->found_posts;`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by filtering here, but just try it out first with some given user id,

Comment: not sure what you mean by filter, but you can e.g. use `get_the_author_meta('ID')` within a loop for the current author id.

Comment: OK how can I use $count_per_author in the index.php while loop as a filter? In the arguments 'author' => $post->post_author is this right since this is placed in another loop as a filter

Comment: create e.g. a helper function for the counting stuff and feed it with relevant input arguments. yes $post->post_author should work too.

Comment: Here is the real question how do I turn the within 24 hours query into a helper function? Should I create another question on stack exchange?

Comment: Check the php docs and define your own function, remember to prefix it to avoid possible name collision. Example function wpse_count_per_user( ... ){ ... }. Sorry don't have much more time now.